# Postgresql:Update text column with value from another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I'm new to postgresql and  need help with an update script where I can insert the corresponding ID between path2 and the filename if there is none.This will be done on multiple records.

```
table1  
id       name     path
111      Test1    /path1/path2/file1.png
222      Test1    /path1/path2/222/file2.png
333      Test3    /path1/path2/file3.png
444      Test3    https:test/path1/path2/file4.png
555      Test4    /path1/path2/file5.png
```

After update only IDs 111 and 333 will be affected and the expected is
/path1/path2/111/file1.png
/path1/path2/333/file3.png

I am using this select to get the records that need updating.

```
select * from table1
where name in ('Test1','Test3')
and path like '/path1/path2/%'
and path not like '/path1/path2/%/%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
update table1 
   set path = replace(path, '/path2/', concat('/path2/', id::text, '/'))
 where path !~ concat('/path2/', id::text, '/');
UPDATE 4

select * from table1;

 id  | name  |                 path                 
-----+-------+--------------------------------------
 222 | Test1 | /path1/path2/222/file2.png
 111 | Test1 | /path1/path2/111/file1.png
 333 | Test3 | /path1/path2/333/file3.png
 444 | Test3 | https:test/path1/path2/444/file4.png
 555 | Test4 | /path1/path2/555/file5.png
(5 rows)
```